# Unable to receive data from socket on Docker Windows

Tags: docker, sockets

I have a webserver listening on some port. I dockerize this server and publish its port with the command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 image-tag
```

Now I write a short Java client socket connecting to localhost on this port (it is able to connect). However, when I read data from this socket via the readLine function, it always returns me null. It shouldn't. Can someone point me some direction on how to troubleshoot this? Things I have tried:

1. This webserver and client works fine without docker.
2. Using my docker installation, I'm able to pull the getting-started app and it works fine. (means there is no problem with my docker, it still can publish port)
3. My docker pulls only the openjdk:latest as the base image. Other than that, nothing special.
4. The docker is Linux Docker on Windows Host.
5. The port the webserver is running on is correct and the same as the published port.

I would be very happy if someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making the server app inside container listen on address 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost, I'm able to solve the problem.